# Conditional compilation new csproj and visual studio solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I have the following in my csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="WebControls/**/*" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'" />
    <Compile Remove="Lucene/**/*" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I'm not even sure if this is the right approach, I'm trying to avoid having to go through those files and add a conditional compilation symbol such as "#if NET462".

The problem is that those files disappear from the solution explorer when I add that to csproj, is there a way to switch the target platform to net462 in the solution explorer so that they show again?

Comment: is `netstandard2.0` the first TFM listed in your `<TargetFrameworks>`?

Comment: Yes, it is the first